# VS2015 AngularJS Typescript definition not fully working

Tags: angularjs, typescript, intellisense

I have installed Angular TypeScript defintion typing (VS2015). 
The typings seem to work mostly including "ng-" directives within the HTML or "angular." will work BUT when i try to use intellisense on an injected variable such as $scope... no luck and the intellisense does not show up.

Is this a limit of the DefinitelyTyped https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped library or should it be working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't work out of box because you can add anything to your `$scope` object.

I think there are two ways to make compiler happy. The first way requires less typing:

```
function Controller($scope: ng.IScope) {
    $scope.$broadcast('myEvent');
    $scope['title'] = 'Yabadabadu';
}
```

and the second way is:

```
interface IMyScope extends ng.IScope {
  title: string;
}

function Controller($scope: IMyScope) {
    $scope.$broadcast('myEvent');
    $scope.title = 'Yabadabadu';
}
```

I use the first approach for simple directives and the second for more complex ones.

Answer (score 1):

I annotated $scope with the interface ng.IScope. The compiler now knows $scope has methods

```js
function Controller($scope: ng.IScope) {
    $scope.$broadcast('myEvent');
    $scope.title = 'Yabadabadu';
}
```

Comment: when working with TypeScript I find the ControllerAs syntax to be much more natural, but this is a good solution.